# What does invalid cache file in /var/cache/fontconfig mean?

Tags: debian, fonts, fontconfig

I was running -

```
$ sudo fc-cache -fv
```

when I got this output -

```
/var/cache/fontconfig: invalid cache file: 54a8ef1a9100c0b4081d409cc341e1e8-le64.cache-7
```

What does it mean and are there any means to remove that invalid cache file so the message doesn't come back.

Running fontconfig 2.13.1-2 on Debian testing.

Comment: Bump...........